Nuance of 相場が決まっている
The word 相場,  market (price), has a quite common additional sense that can mean reputation/estimation/esteem (according to conventional wisdom), used most commonly in the phrase 相場が決まっている, "to be the (social) convention [that]...".
An example:

夏のレジャーと言えば海か山と相場が決まっている.　
It is taken for granted that summer leisure time should be spent at the sea or in the mountains.

I have looked at several dictionaries and none of them have described where this additional meaning of esteem (according to conventional wisdom) has come from. It seems quite different than the base meaning of market (price), and so I figured that this separate usage had to come from something specific.
Where did this sense, particularly the phrase 相場が決まっている, originate from?

I'm not sure what you mean by "esteem" here. Is it synonymous to being highly regarded and having high status?

評価 can both mean "evaluation" as well as "recognition (of something's value)". Esteem is a rather formal way to refer to the latter definition, as in "There has been a drop in public esteem for teachers."
That said, I just copied the English definition on jisho which included "esteem" as a possible translation.

I would say it's similar to "average" and "expectation" in a broad sense. 相場 is like the statistically expected value of something when individual participants give different price tags to it (or the price goes up and down over time).
When you say Aと相場が決まっている figuratively, you are not saying it's a superb choice nor the best choice / the most accurate valucation. You are saying that it's just the most common answer or what an (hypothetical) average person would come up with. If you want, you could follow up then by saying how the conventional wisdom is wrong in the given specific situation.

In the context of 相場, "market" as in "market price" does not refer to places like supermarkets or Amazon. Instead, the term 相場 is primarily used in places where prices fluctuate significantly over short periods, such as the stock market, gold market or fish wholesale markets. For example, 相場師 refers to an expert stock/currency trader who does not deal in actual physical goods. In such environments, it is essential to have extensive knowledge (or "conventional wisdom") to evaluate the value of things and predict future, hence the derivative meaning.
"Market price" in the sense of prices found in retail markets is called 市場価格 or 小売価格.
